# Get neat content from Wiki page. (MediaWiki API)

Tags: android, mediawiki, wikipedia-api

I want to get a content page from Wiki in this format (the picture below) then show it in WebView. It means the content includes text and links.

[image: Einstein]

I tried this but the output seems to be messy.
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&titles=Albert_Einstein&format=xmlfm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `index.php?action=render`; [an example](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Albert_Einstein&action=render). This returns the HTML of the page content with no sidebar/header/footer HTML. You'll have to match and remove infoboxes yourself.

Reference: [MediaWiki — Manual:Parameters to index.php](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aParameters_to_index.php#Actions).

Answer (score 5):

I stumbled across this answer a year later and would like to note that the `?action=render` parameter [has been depreciated](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aParameters_to_index.php#render) as of this post.

The recommended method is to use the [Mediawiki API to parse the wikitext](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aParsing_wikitext).

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML generated by mediawiki instead of wikicode.

BTW: look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aDump#Why_not_just_retrieve_data_from_wikipedia.org_at_runtime.3F)

Comment: I read the link and don't understand what you mean. MediaWiki doesn't generate HTML format.

Comment: Link is about general idea "I want to get a content page from Wiki in this format". Massive queries will result in blocked access to Wikipedia.

Comment: @HTML - I thought about importing html from "bodyContent" div